# How to compile original sass file into multiple browser compatible versions css

Tags: css, compass-sass

As I know the **compass** can help you compile its syntax into multiple browser support versions.

Now I write sass file,

I will use tool to compile it into css.

But I wonder know how to compile it into multi-browser support css like compass can do.

Eg.

## Input

```
@import "compass/css3";
.box{
  @include border-radius(5px);
}
```

## output

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
-ms-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

But the problem is I only know to write css (like the following),

How do I convert the following css snippet into multiple browser compatible css version ?

Because it doesn't work on Firefox but works on Chrome

Any idea ?

```
.container {
  .categorysection {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:960px;
    &.grey {
      background: #eee;
    }
  }
  .grid-col {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 6px;
  }  
  h3.heading {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .grid-col {
        float: none !important;
        /*display: block;*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling this in a Sass file or trying to write this to a CSS file?  All your CSS is nested, so if you are doing this in a CSS file then ya, it won't work.

Comment: @SeanStopnik this is sass file, i will use tool to compile it into css. but i wonder know how to compile it into multi-browser support css like compass can do.

Comment: Nothing in this above code is browser specific.  It will work in all browsers. If its not working in FF, but only working in your default browser(Chrome), Im guessing you are not compiling correctly, and Chrome is just using the cached css.  I'm just guessing here...   but you do not have anything in that code that wouldn't work in all browsers...  except the fact that its nested.